# Installing GitBlit GO as Service in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: git, service, ubuntu-14.04

I downloaded it (version 1.6.0), unpacked it in /opt/gitblit (ubuntu server 14.04.1), configured http to 8280 and disabled https assigning 0 (I expose it by https using nginx).

I created gitblit user and added it to 'sudo' group by running: `sudo adduser gitblit sudo` (`gitblit` user has a strong password).

I installed it as a service by running: `/opt/gitblit/install-service-ubuntu.sh`.

I tried to start it by running: `sudo service gitblit start`. The message `Starting gitblit server` appears. It's the only message.

When I hit -in the same local machine- `http://127.0.0.1:8280`, the connection could not be made. When I run `sudo netstat -anp | grep 8280`, nothing appears.

I see no error messages, but the server is not starting.

**Question**: What am I missing?

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: What error logs? could not find them

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The reason the service would not start in my case is that the gitblit user did not have permission to access any of the /opt/gitblit files.  This is because (doh) I had installed gitblit as root.  The solution was simple:

```
chown -R gitblit:gitblit /opt/gitblit
```

Comment: This is the correct way: chown -R gitblit:gitblit /opt/gitblit